# Sync music with Windows Media Player, but not to .alb files?

Tags: sync, sd-card, music-player

Right now, I manually copy and paste my music to my phone, which is arduous and and incredibly annoying (I just had all of my playlists and new music list themselves **twice** in my library). I would like to use Windows Media Player or another program to sync my music to my phone's SD card. This works, but it syncs them in a compressed file with the extension `.alb` for album. Is there any way to disable this compression either on WMP or Android?